# How to use Typescript type object indexing for typed generic functions?

Tags: typescript

I have an api with a typed map from api name to api input object type:

```
type ApiInputTypes = {
    doThis: { x: number }
    doThat: { y: string }
}

type ApiNames = keyof ApiInputTypes
```

My goal is to write a generic function that can handle any of these api requests, but I'm getting a type error where I would not expect it.

```
function handleApi<Name extends ApiNames>(name: Name, args: ApiInputTypes[Name]) {
    if (name === "doThis") {
        args.x // Error
    } else {
        args.y // Error
    }
 }
```

Ironically, this still works though...

```
// But this works...
handleApi("doThis", { x: 190 })
```

Any ideas? Here's a [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20ApiInputTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doThis%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doThat%3A%20%7B%20y%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ApiNames%20%3D%20keyof%20ApiInputTypes%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleApi%3CName%20extends%20ApiNames%3E(name%3A%20Name%2C%20args%3A%20ApiInputTypes%5BName%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(name%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22doThis%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20args.x%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20args.y%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20But%20this%20works...%0D%0AhandleApi(%22doThis%22%2C%20%7B%20x%3A%20190%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A) link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control flow analysis currently does not narrow generic type parameters (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)).  It looks like this issue has been reported multiple times with multiple [suggestions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17713) for dealing with it.  Nothing's been implemented yet.   For now there are just workarounds.

One possible workaround is to package `name` and `args` into a single value `nameAndArgs`, whose type you specify as a union of the two possible cases.

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type NameAndArgs = ValueOf<{ [N in ApiNames]: { name: N, args: ApiInputTypes[N] } }>;

function handleApi<Name extends ApiNames>(name: Name, args: ApiInputTypes[Name]) {
  const nameAndArgs = { name, args } as NameAndArgs;
  if (nameAndArgs.name === "doThis") {
    nameAndArgs.args.x // okay
  } else {
    nameAndArgs.args.y // okay
  }
}
```

Note that the `NameAndArgs` property is equivalent to

```
type NameAndArgs = {
    name: "doThis";
    args: {
        x: number;
    };
} | {
    name: "doThat";
    args: {
        y: string;
    };
}
```

The function works because the single `nameAndArgs` variable can be narrowed, and the `name` and `args` properties stay narrowed in the relevant clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the types in an enum

```
export enum ApiInputTypes {
  doThis = 'doThis',
  doThat = 'doThat'
}

function handleApi(name: ApiInputTypes) {
  if(name === ApiInputTypes.doThis){
   //doThis
  }
}
```